# Wrap text in DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview

I am using DataGridView in winform application (Framework 2.0) 
I am setting

`DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True and AutoSizeRowsMode =        DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells`

But it is not wrapping text in cell.
I am using following code to add rows in DataGridView.

```
Grid.Rows.Add(new object(){"sdfsdfsdf sdfdsf"})
```

If i use datatable and assign it using Grid.DataSource it wraps text properly.

Has any one solution for this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Assuming "object()" is supposed to be "object[]", this code should work. There is something wrong elsewhere. Try to create a new project and do the things you describe and check if it is working. Also, text won't wrap if there are no word breaks (spaces etc).

Comment: yes it is object array. i already tried with new blank project. if i am trying with same data using DataTable and Grid.DataSource, It is working. Just Grid.Rows.Add() is not working with same data.